# Phantom element being rendered in Chrome for Android only--disappears upon Inspect

Tags: html, css, rgba, chrome-for-android

Pulling my hair out over this one and I appreciate any help I can get.

Visit this website using Chrome for Android: http://summit2014.cochranesupply.com/

This problem in my experience is exclusive to Chrome for Android and I believe it may be a bug but I need a workaround.

Scroll down to the Contact section and rummage through it. You should find at least one instance of this solid bar of color:

[image: Example]

What I have found out about this bar:

- It is rendered behind the "Contact" block of content

  - I believe this is true because if I use a transparent image (.png) for a background instead of rgba(255,255,255,0.9), I still see it, but if I make that same image opaque, I do not see it.
- It has a background color of approximately 10% opacity white

  - I tested if this was tied to my rgba(255,255,255,0.9) background color for the sections, it is not. Changing the section background to a red tint or a solid color did not change the phantom element's color/tint.
- If I connect the Chrome debug tools for desktop, the very second that I hit Inspect, the phantom bars disappear, both on my Android device and in the emulated view of it.
- If I flip my phone sideways to render the content wide, and then flip it back, the phantom bars disappear.
- I have removed all css table formatting to no avail. I have remove all combinations of css associated with that block of content to no avail. The only thing that makes it go away is removing a background from the sections entirely, or using an opaque background that presumably hides these phantom blocks.
- I have removed all my custom script at the bottom of the page to no avail.
- I have removed all manner of content surrounding this block of content to no avail.
- Different combinations of content make the bars render in different places. Sometimes, when switching back to the original configuration, the bars will render differently than they once did, even though all the code has returned to normal.

I don't know what to do anymore. I was hopping the Chrome debug would work out and that I'd be able to identify what exactly is being rendered here but I cannot, as the phantom elements immediately disappear once I view the CSS/HTML with the Inspect feature.

Here also is the relevant CSS/HTML for this block of content:

HTML:

```
        <div class="row section">
            <div class="slot-6-7-8-9">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>CONTACT
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot-6-7-8-9">
                <div class="section-text" style="text-align: center;">
                    General inquiries and sales:<br>
                    <span class="semibold" style="font-size: 1.1em">800-482-4894</span><br>
                    <a href="mailto:sales@cochranesupply.com">sales@cochranesupply.com</a><br>
                    <a class="semibold" href="http://www.cochranesupply.com">www.cochranesupply.com</a><br>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/CochraneSupply" target="_blank" class="social-media"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="color: #00aced;"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cochrane-Supply-Engineering/148656168524834" target="_blank" class="social-media"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color: #3b5998;"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups?about=&gid=2878019&trk=anet_ug_grppro" target="_blank" class="social-media"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="color: #007bb6;"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/scochrane.jpg" alt="Scott Cochrane">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Scott Cochrane
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                President
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:scochrane@cochranesupply.com">scochrane</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/dladwig.jpg" alt="Dave Ladwig">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Dave Ladwig
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                General Manager
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:dladwig@cochranesupply.com">dladwig</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/nconklin.jpg" alt="Nicole Conklin">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Nicole Conklin
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                OEM Sales
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:nconklin@cochranesupply.com">nconklin</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/ptrainor.jpg" alt="Pat Trainor">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Pat Trainor
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                OEM Sales
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:ptrainor@cochranesupply.com">ptrainor</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/mrosu.jpg" alt="Mike Rosu">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Mike Rosu
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Northeast Detroit, MI
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                313-387-3025
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:mrosu@cochranesupply.com">mrosu</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/dlawson.jpg" alt="Dave Lawson">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Dave Lawson
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Southwest Detroit, MI
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                313-387-3025
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:dlawson@cochranesupply.com">dlawson</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/drademacher.jpg" alt="Dan Rademacher">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Dan Rademacher
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Western Michigan
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-306-5104
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:drademacher@cochranesupply.com">drademacher</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/gwidenmier.jpg" alt="Greg Widenmier">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Greg Widenmier
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Northern Michigan
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                989-859-6062
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:gwidenmier@cochranesupply.com">gwidenmier</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/thorace.jpg" alt="Tim Horace">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Tim Horace
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Ohio
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                419-243-1711
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:thorace@cochranesupply.com">thorace</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/gwitt.jpg" alt="Greg Witt">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Greg Witt
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Kentucky
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                502-208-3640
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:gwitt@cochranesupply.com">gwitt</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/plemire.jpg" alt="Patrick Lemire">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Patrick Lemire
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Canada
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                514-609-7114
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:plemire@cochranesupply.com">plemire</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/nrichmond.jpg" alt="Nicole Richmond">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Nicole Richmond
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Marketing, Training Coordinator
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:nrichmond@cochranesupply.com">nrichmond</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/mmitchell.jpg" alt="Mike Mitchell">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Mike Mitchell
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Chief Technology Officer
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:mmitchell@cochranesupply.com">mmitchell</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/jmitchell.jpg" alt="Joe Mitchell">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Joe Mitchell
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Tech Services, Instructor
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:jmitchell@cochranesupply.com">jmitchell</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/kcrabill.jpg" alt="Kevin Crabill">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Kevin Crabill
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Tech Services, Developer
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:kcrabill@cochranesupply.com">kcrabill</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot-8-9">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/rvandermeer.jpg" alt="Ron Vandermeer">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Ron Vandermeer
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Tech Services, Instructor
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:rvandermeer@cochranesupply.com">rvandermeer</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slot-6-7">
                    <div class="contact-container">
                        <div class="contact-picture">
                            <img src="./images/employees/arickle.jpg" alt="Aaron Rickle">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="contact-title-bold">
                                Aaron Rickle
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-title-text">
                                Tech Services, Developer
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                800-482-4894
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-bold">
                                Email
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-text">
                                <a href="mailto:arickle@cochranesupply.com">arickle</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.contact-container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.contact-picture {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1px 14px 0 14px;
}

.contact-picture img {
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-info {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.contact-title-bold {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #d92027;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.contact-title-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d92027;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.contact-bold {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #505050;
}

.contact-text {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Please help @_@ At the moment I've mostly given up and deemed it a bug for Chrome for Android, but I would love to figure out some kind of workaround, understand why this is happening, or really be certain that it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a little while looking at this issue and here's what I've found:

- The phantom bar/s were present when I first loaded your page, and not just in the contact block.
- When I refreshed the browser, the bars vanished completely. When I refreshed again, they returned, only in the contact block.
- When I flipped my device to landscape the phantom bars vanished again and did not return when I flipped back.

The fact that the phantom bars are not consistently displayed suggest a bug with Chrome for Android.

I realise this doesn't answer your question but hopefully it gives you a bit more info to work with.